# How to make Maven look *only* in a specific folder for dependencies?

Tags: maven

Because of reasons, I need to have a local, not-connected-to-anything copy of all dependencies for a certain app. I have a script that downloads those dependencies and stores them in a structure not unlike a local Maven repository (like in `.m2/repository`).

Now, I want to make a sort of "dummy app" that checks my codebase against that repository, looking *only* there *and nowhere else*. The dummy app contains the real app's pom.xml files, and a few Java files so that (among other things) the Swagger generator is actually triggered.

In my the parent `pom.xml` of the dummy, I added

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>downloaded</id>
            <name>Downloaded dependencies</name>
            <url>file://path/to/local/repository</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>downloaded</id>
            <name>Downloaded dependencies</name>
            <url>file://path/to/local/repository</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

This doesn't work, because the local repo is empty and the dummy app build (`mvn package`) still succeeds.

I also tried adding a `settings.xml` to the dummy app, but that doesn't seem to do anything either:

```
<settings>
    <localRepository>path/to/local/repository</localRepository>
</settings>
```

For reference, I've done the same thing in Gradle, and that works fine:

in `settings.gradle`

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'path/to/local/repository'
        }
    }
}
```

and in `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            name 'local'
            url "file://path/to/local/repository"
        }
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            name 'local'
            url "file://path/to/local/repository"
        }
    }
}
```

So, how do I achieve the above Gradle config using only Maven?

Comment: Have you tried: `mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=..`

Comment: That does seem to help, thanks.

Comment: @khmarbaise if you're interested in converting that comment to an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use `mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=<location>` which defines the location of the local cache via command line option.